# Are the subgroups of $S_n$ symmetric?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I have a quick question. Are all the subgroups of $S_n$ symmetric as well?

Comment: What have you tried?  I bet you'll be able to answer your own question quickly if you look at $n = 3$.

Comment: If you want to bump your question, you could do it with an edit to include more information on what you have tried or haven't tried to solve your question. Not by making the title completely and utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean, "is every subgroup of a symmetric group isomorphic to a symmetric group?", the answer is no.

For example, look at the subgroup generated by a $k$-cycle, with $k>2$ inside of a symmetric group of order greater than $2$. This will be a cyclic group, and no symmetric group $S_n$ is cyclic for $n>2$.